# Navigation issue when tabbing cells in Telerik RadGrid

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, telerik, radgrid

I'm developing a C# solution using MVVM with a Silverlight Telerik RadGrid.  I have a View that contains 3 grids, each with a set of checkboxes above it.  I can successfully tab through the set of checkboxes with the focus then moving to the RadGrid but when tabbing to the last cell of each row in the grid, I sometimes have to tab twice in order to leave the cell.  In addition, instead of focus moving to the first cell of the next row in the grid, the focus returns to the first checkbox above the grid and upon tabbing through all of the checkboxes, the focus is returned to the next row of cells in the grid.

I need to be able to navigate to each cell in the grid row by clicking the Tab button only once.  Also, upon tabbing from the last cell focus should return to the first cell of the next row.  This behavior should be repeated for each grid row.  At that point, focus should move to the next set of checkboxes after the grid.

Here is a snapshot of my grid settings.  The last cell of each row contains a hyperlink button:

```
<telerik:RadGridView 
    Grid.Row="1" 
    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="grdCars"
    x:Name="grdCars"  
    SelectionMode="Single" 
    SelectionUnit="Cell"  
    CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
    CanUserFreezeColumns="False" 
    Style="{StaticResource gridviewStyle}" 
    ShowColumnHeaders="true" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding FilterCarList}" 
    CanUserSortColumns="False" 
    ActionOnLostFocus="CommitEdit" 
    TabNavigation="Local" MinHeight="50" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    TabIndex="290"  
    CanUserDeleteRows="False">
```

Answer (score 0):

use something like this
XAML:

```
<telerik:RadGridView  KeyDown="grd_KeyDown"/>
```

C#

```
private void grd_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
                {
                    if (e.Key == Key.Return || e.Key == Key.Tab)
                    {
                        MoveToNext();
                        //e.Handled = true;
                    }

                }
        private void MoveToNext()
                {
                    var cmd = RadGridViewCommands.MoveNext as RoutedUICommand;
                    cmd.Execute(null, grd);

                }
```